# SQL update values from table

Tags: sql, select, sql-update

I'm seriously struggling with some *easy* stuff.

Currently I have 2 tables (tmp_jmo and persons)

```
table tmp_jmo
----------
ID     ADRESS     PERSON_ID
115    Street 1   (null)
120    Street 2   (null)
121    Street 3   (null)

Table persons
ID    NAME      PERSON_ID
----------
115    John       14
120    Ellen      27
121    Mark       114
```

Now I want to update the `Peson_id` from `tmp_jmo` with the values from `person_id` (persons table)

In this case I've getting the error that there are to many values

```
Update tmp_jmo t SET person_id = persons.person_id where tmp_jmo.id = persons.id;
```

I've also tried to with temporary data but also failing.

I'm sorry to interrupt you with this kind of questions but it's ruining my day!

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In Standard SQL, you can do:

```
update tmp_jmo t 
    set person_id = (select p.person_id from persons p where tmp_jmo.id = p.id);
```

Many databases also support `join` or `from` in `update`s, but that is database-specific syntax.